# How to Set & Get ID in JQuery Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, cordova

Thanks for read my question.I am working on Mobile Application using PhoneGap.
I am using HTML 5 database to store data.

My one of the table is `Company` which have `com_id & com_name`.
I have create simple search textbox using [this](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#default).That's working properly with static & dynamic array.

Here is my bit of code which fetch records from database and set in *auto complete*.

```
function All_Company_QuerySuccess(tx, results) {
    console.log("Returned rows = " + results.rows.length);
    var com_array = []; // init array
    //this will return user_id if user exist else return "no user"
    if (!results.rowsAffected) {
        for (var index = 0; index < results.rows.length; index++) {
            var item = results.rows.item(index);
            var com_id = item.com_id; // company id
            var com_name = item.com_name; // company name 
            com_array.push(com_name) // add value into array
        }
        // assign drop down
        $(function () {

            $("#pur_com_text").autocomplete({
                source: com_array,
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    selected_company = ui.item.value;
                    alert(selected_company);
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

**Html code**

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
<input name="" id="pur_com_text" placeholder="Search Company" value="" type="search" onClick="Get_All_Company()" />
</div>
```

While i will type in search box it will shows me company name.

**Issue :**

I want to get that selected `company ID (com_id)` for further task.I don't know how can i get that or what should i do for that.

Please Guide me how to solve this issue.

Comment: You could create a HTML element and return that, such as <p id="' + item.com_id + '">"' + item.com_name + '"</p>.

Comment: @andrew-buchan Thanks ,so if i create '<p id>' and add that value in my loop then how i will get that id in autocomplete event ?

Comment: Assuming when you return the autocomplete entry you can just use any accepted way of getting the id of the current element. Can you jsfiddle us what you have?

Comment: @andrew-buchan okay let me paste my code in JSFiddle. so you can get idea

Comment: @andrew-buchan here is [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GrJQ6/)

Comment: check here i have update http://jsfiddle.net/GrJQ6/7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take two arrays instead of one.

- `com_array_name`  : push names in it through that for loop
- `com_array_id`    : push id's in it through that same for loop.

In autocomplete plugin,

- give `source` as  `com_array_name`
- and in `select` property, give `alert(com_array_id[com_array_name.indexOf(ui.item.value)]);`

This will work if the names are unique in the array.

Answer (score 0):

I would simple create some kind of map like in java.
Create a new object and add for each companyname an property or index (which is IMHO in js the same) so if the company name is unique you will be able to resolve the id with the company name.

```
var myMap = {};
// in your loop:
myMap[com_name]=com_id;
// access:
alert(myMap["Example Company Inc."]);
```